# Cómo introducir dentro de una variable de sesión, una variable de sesión formando un nombre compusto

Tags: php

¿Cómo se podría crear un nombre compuesto de una variable de sesión?
Ejemplo: Si una variable es $_SESSION['vehículos'] y otra variable es $_SESSION['nuevos'], poder crear una nueva variable de sesión llamada $_SESSION['vehiculosnuevos']. Crear un nombre compuesto.

Saludos.

Comment: Debes dar más detalles en tu pregunta que son claves. Por ejemplo: ¿hay más claves en la variable de sesión o son sólo esas dos? ¿qué piensas hacer luego con las claves separadas `vehiculos` y `nuevos`, seguirán siendo parte del array o deben ser eliminadas? ¿Y con los valores que tenga cada clave? Según lo que quieras hacer entonces se podrá determinar cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Ademas algo muy importante que debes aclarar es eso que comentas en la respuesta dada de que *va automático*  ¿?  Mientras más claro seas mejores respuestas tendrás.

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear un array bidimensional, exemplo `$_SESSION['vehiculos']['nuevos']`, y hacer todo con esta variable bidimensional

Comment: Utilizar array bidimensional es una opción. ¿Cómo puedo concatenar dos variables de sesión para crear uno bidimensiona? Ya que va automático. Gracias.